# html/css full background overlay div inside another div

Tags: css, image, background, overlay

I have a simple **< div >** (without fixed hegiht) with a text in it:

```
<div id="section">
<div class="container">
<h1>text</h1>
<p>More text</p>
</div>
<!-- <div id="overlay"></div> -->
</div>
```

The CSS for this  is something like:

```
#section {
    background: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

It's possibile to add a div with a transparent image background?

The overlay sholud be hover the main red background, but under the text.

I think is something like this, but dont works:

```
#section #overlay {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px; /* ??? */
    background: green;
    opacity: 0.1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#section {
background: red;
display: block;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}
#container {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
z-index: 9999;
}
#overlay {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, how about something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="section">
    <div id="container">
        <h1>My background is transparent!</h1>
        <p>More text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#section {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: red;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    left: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

Results here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0o2gya0q/2/)

If that's not what you wanted, can you be more specific about the positioning?

Answer (score 0):

try below example using jquery ui will reduce the effort

```
    <div id="dialog">Your non-modal dialog</div>
<a href="#" id="open">Open dialog</a>

    $('#open').click(function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');

});



jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        open: function(){
            jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click',function(){
                jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
            })
        }
    });
});
```